# Power Over Ethernet (Pi Zero Mod)

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm looking to make 20-30 IoT devices, with the pi zero.
The price point is perfect, the only downside is that it doesn't have an Ethernet jack and the power adapter is not included.

I found a mod that deals with both of these issues, however it would involve a lot of soldering. The mod takes a USB to Ethernet adapter and 48 to 5 volt converter and allows the device to be both powered and connected to the internet with just an Ethernet cable.

With 3D printing or Milling is it possible to make something that snap fits the components together and mitigate a lot of soldering?
Is it possible to print or mill something that will do the 48 to 5 volt conversion?

Components:

1. Two male micro USB heads
2. 48 to 5 volt converter
3. Ethernet adapter board
4. Pi zero

[image]

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your question, this is totally impossible with 3D printing. I voted to "close as unclear what you're asking" (though that might not be the best reason) because this question is based on a total misunderstanding of what 3D printing is.

Comment: While it is not easily possible to print the solider connections, it would be possible to 3D print a mount that holds your 3 components together on a single surface.  Wiring would be separate from this though.

Comment: Hi, Derek, I find you question very intriguing! However, you are probably a few years too early in asking this question, since the current state of 3D printing (at least the kind we typically discuss on this site) just isn't there yet. I am therefore putting your question on hold for now since most answers would be mere speculation. Please let us know if you would like your question reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[3D Print A Solderless Circuit Board](http://www.instructables.com/id/3D-Printing-3D-Print-A-Solderless-Circuit-Board/)

I think this was the solution I was looking for, unless someone else knows a method that's cheaper, faster, safer, etc.

Comment: Basically your printing a component mounting chassis and using brush in traces to make a circuit.  While this works you really are not printing a circuit board and can achieve the same concept by just painting traces on a perf board.  Another option to the paint on traces is rolls of adhesive backed copper trace.  But to use either effectively long term with reliable quality in a data circuit you need to solder.  There is conductive filament which added as one of the feeds on a dual extruder can print a circuit for limited power runs.